# Show the page while testing with PhantomJS through Selenium

Tags: python, django, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm making a test of my Django app using Selenium and PhantomJS. I'm debugging a failure of the test. Is there a way to make the headless PhantomJS suddenly show like a real browser on the screen so I could easily debug the problem?

Comment: You may want to take a look here: http://phantomjs.org/troubleshooting.html. But no, you cannot open PhantomJS. As I'm sure you're aware, it is a headless browser and I don't believe they provide a head in the .exe

Comment: How about just exchanging PhantomJS for Firefox?

Comment: This is not necessarily what you're asking for, but I've often found my best debugging happens by printing the entire page html to bash, using something like `print(self.driver.find_element_by_tage_name('html')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's not possible to open browser, you could take screenshots at the failure point. That would help you see why and where your test is failing. http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html

Comment: Works well. I use this code: `PIL.Image.open(io.BytesIO(browser.get_screenshot_as_png())).show()` to see the screenshot immediately in the debugger.